# Copy/paste a bullet list from office to formular PHP

Tags: php, list, ms-office

I'm developping a website and I have a problem. Some users copy bullet list from ms-Office and paste it in a textarea that I manage in php. 
[Here is the error that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfb9Y.jpg)

How can I manage that? I've tried this:

```
$field_value = preg_replace('/\x03/', '', $field_value);
```

But is there something more generic that could manage all kind of bullet list from ms-office?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I don't know if it's the best one but it works fine. I used this regex:

```
$field_value = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ&`_.,;@#%~'\"\+\\n\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\=\!\<\>\|\:\-\s\\\\]/u", "", $field_value);
```